# PHP IF condition advise needed

Tags: php, syntax

I'm using emails as username to login into a site being developed, now if a user updates their email from the profile page, how can i make sure that my email checking statement doesnt catch the user's email as already registered in the database.

**the page**
[image: profile]

```
 /* Now we will store the values submitted by form in variable */
           $fullname=$_POST['fullname'];
           $dob=$_POST['dob'];
           $address=$_POST['address'];
           $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];           
           $telephone=$_POST['telephone'];

$queryuser=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email='$myusername' ");
$checkuser=mysql_num_rows($queryuser);

if($checkuser != 0) 
{ 
$Merr[]='&raquo; Sorry this email is already registered!';
}
else {$insert_user=mysql_query("UPDATE CUSTOMER SET SYNTAX HERE");
```

Now these are the fields in question;

> (name, dob, address, email, telephone) VALUES ('$fullname', '$dob',
>   '$address', '$myusername', '$telephone')

As you can see if the user changes the login email then the syntax checks for the email being submitted against the database, however if the user leaves the email unchanged he will get the error because it is found in the database.

I was thinking of something like;

```
if($checkuser != 0) {
  if($myusername == $_POST['myusername'])
   (...dont show error.)
```

but my php skills are limited. can anyone advise please, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Now we will store the values submitted by form in variable */
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];           


$queryuser=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM customer WHERE email='$myusername' ");
$checkuser=mysql_num_rows($queryuser);

/*Mysql_fetch_row will select the first row from the query and put it into a 
multidimensional array. As you only want 1 e-mail associated with one user the query
should only ever select one row anyway.  */
$row = mysql_fetch_row($queryuser);

if($checkuser != 0) 
{ 
      if($row[0] != $SESSION['username'])
      {
      //ERROR
      }

}
else {
//Update details
}
```

That way you can just submit the e-mail along with any other inputs and if the e-mail hasn't changed you wont need to do anything.

Also you've said your posting the logged in users username. I would imagine you would actually want to be using [sessions](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) to do that.

And don't forget to [escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) the POST data for security.

Also the INSERT INTO  should that not be an [update](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlupdate.php) statement if they are updating their e-mail address?

Comment: Editing my answer i've realised $myusername is actually the posted username, you don't want to do that you want to use fetch_row

Comment: Also as a side I find it helpful to name variables with capitalization on words after first for example $myUserName

Comment: What does `if($row[0]` mean.. which row is it referring to

Comment: Notice how I changed the SQL select just to select the email, remember that * in SQL selects every row but you can also list the rows in the select so then the number refers to the order you have selected them. I've a feeling you can also refer to them using $row['email'] but i'm not sure.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a comment to my use of fetch_row

Comment: Hiya, Ive completely changed my code, i think im gona need to post a new question.

Comment: Okay, well if you want to link me to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating the database use Update..
Update customers set email='$username' where email='$username'.

you can't use the same form for registering and updating information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you keep an id sort of thing for the users? If so you could check for the existing email addresses that is not the current users email address.

Comment: Yes each customer has an id `cus_id`